# Show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Bbb R} f(x) g(x+n) dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Problem: Let $f, g \in L^2(\Bbb R)$. Show that
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Bbb R} f(x) g(x+n) dx=0$$**

Solution: Consider $\Bbb R = S_n \cup T_n$ where: $$S_n =\{ x \ | \ |x| \leq \frac{n}{2} \} \text{ and } T_n =\{ x \ | \ |x| > \frac{n}{2}\}$$
$$ \int_{\Bbb R} f(x) g(x+n)dx = \int_{S_n} f(x) g(x+n) dx + \int_{T_n} f(x) g(x+n) dx$$

By Holder inequality and translation invariant property
\begin{align*}
\Bigg|\int_{S_n} f(x) g(x+n) dx \Bigg| & \leq \|f\|_2 \Big( \int_{S_n} g(x+n)^2 dx \Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
& \leq \|f\|_2 \Big( \int_{|x|>\frac{n}{2}} (g(x))^2 dx \Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
& =\|f\|_2 \cdot \epsilon\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align*}
because $\Big| \int_{|x| > \frac{n}{2}} g(x)^2 dx \Big| < \epsilon$

Same argument for $T_n$, therefore the whole thing is less than $\epsilon$.

Is this solution correct? Is there any other way of solving this problem Thanks

Comment: Correct. Just a minor thing is to put the absolute value in the integral $\int_{S_n} f(x)g(x+n) dx$.

Comment: How do we deduce that $\|f\|_2 \Big( \int_{S_n} g(x+n)^2 dx \Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq \|f\|_2 \Big( \int_{|x|>\frac{n}{2}} (g(x))^2 dx \Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$? In particular, how are we changing our integration from over $S_n$ to $|x|>\frac{n}{2}?$

Answer (score 1):

Your argument seems correct. Maybe it could be better to first declare $\varepsilon$, then choose $n_0$ such that  $n\geqslant n_0$, $\int_{|x| > \frac{n}{2}} g(x)^2 dx\lt \varepsilon$ and the same for $f$.

- Unless you did not specify that the norm of $f$ is one, you can only bound by $\|f\|_2 \cdot \epsilon$.
- Consequently, the final bound is $\varepsilon\lVert f\rVert_2+\varepsilon\lVert g\rVert_2$.